# Getting the Value from a Neighbour Input Element with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to get the current value of the INPUT field when I click on the signs.

HTML:

```
<li>
<ul>        
<li class="name">Name:</li>
<li><a spc_action="minus" class="ignite_form_counter fas fa-minus-circle"></a></li>
<li><input type="text" name="count_cat_2_x" value="0"></li>
<li><a spc_action="plus" class="ignite_form_counter fas fa-plus-circle"></a></li>
</ul>
</li>
```

JS:

```
$('li').delegate('.ignite_form_counter', 'click', function(){       
    console.log( $(this).parent().parent('li').closest('input').val() );    
    return false;
});
```

I've tried the approach above but it doesn't work.

Preferably I wouldn't use `closest` because I want to be 100% certain I get the correct value.

Any suggestions how to accomplish this?

Comment: Can you set up a codepen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, `delegate` is a deprecated. You should use the delegated signature of the `on()` method instead. It would also be worth checking your version of jQuery is up to date. You should ideally be using 3.3.1, or 1.12.1 if you need legacy IE support. Secondly, `closest()` is for going *up* the DOM, not down. As such you could couple it with a `find()` call to do what you need:

```js
$(document).on('click', '.ignite_form_counter', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var value = $(this).closest('ul').find('input').val()
  console.log(value);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>
    <ul>
      <li class="name">Name:</li>
      <li>
        <a spc_action="minus" class="ignite_form_counter fas fa-minus-circle">-</a>
      </li>
      <li><input type="text" name="count_cat_2_x" value="0"></li>
      <li>
        <a spc_action="plus" class="ignite_form_counter fas fa-plus-circle">+</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Note that the `on()` call is made on the `document`. Using `li` as you were will attach the event to *every* `li` in the DOM and end up repeating multiple times. You could potentially improve this by using a closer static single parent element which is available in the DOM when the page loads, but your HTML didn't show that to give you an example.

Comment: Noted about `delegate`. Regarding the `li` you said at the end, will it be better if I target the function to `a.ignite_form_counter` or `tml body form ul li ul.expand li ul li a` so I don't potentially trigger unwanted stuff?

Comment: I'd suggest using a single `div` container as the parent. Although there's nothing inherently wrong with just using the `document`

Answer (score 0):

`console.log( $(this).parent().next().find("input").val() );` will help you if you have multiple inputs with plus and minus sign.

```js
$('li').delegate('.ignite_form_counter', 'click', function(){       
    console.log( $(this).parent().next().find("input").val() );    
    return false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li>
<ul>        
<li class="name">Name:</li>
<li><a spc_action="minus" class="ignite_form_counter fas fa-minus-circle">minus</a></li>
<li><input type="text" name="count_cat_2_x" value="50"></li>
<li><a spc_action="plus" class="ignite_form_counter fas fa-plus-circle">plus</a></li>

<li><input type="text" name="count_cat_2_x" value="20"></li>
<li><a spc_action="minus" class="ignite_form_counter fas fa-minus-circle">minus</a></li>
<li><input type="text" name="count_cat_2_x" value="30"></li>
</ul>
</li>
```

You can test it here also.. https://jsfiddle.net/nimittshah/1gvsc8rh/